# Table "App\Model\Table\UsersTable" is not associated with "id" cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm getting this error 'Table "App\Model\Table\UsersTable" is not associated with "id" ', can anyone help how to solve it?

Here is the code of my documents table:

```
class DocumentsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->belongsTo('Users');
        //$this->setForeignKey('user_id');
        $this->setTable('documents');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }
}
```

and here is the code of users table:

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->hasMany('Documents');
        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }
}
```

and here is what the error looks like:

[image]

EDIT: According to the url I'm trying to reach the academics controller, in which I'm loading the documents table.

In calander.ctp, one of the functions of academics table, I use the following code:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
$admin = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$name = $admin->find()->select(['name'])->where([$admin->id => $doc['user_id']])->first();
echo $name;
```

Comment: and when do you get this error? what page are you trying to reach? show your code. btw Conventions over configuration, look in the cookbook how  to do the associasions propperly

Comment: @ Alex Stallen Just edited the post with more details, see if you can help now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$admin` is a table object, but you're trying to access `$admin->id` in your `where` clause. `id` is not a property of table objects, and even if it was, this wouldn't be useful. It should be `where(['Users.id' => $doc['user_id']])`.

Comment: Note, according to your screen shot, the error is happening on line 51 of `Template/Element/forum.ctp`, not in `calendar.ctp`, so it's possible that you have made this mistake in more than one place.